# database model for a rotating rounds system

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Struggling with how to correctly model a database for a fairly simple app i'm putting together. App is just a simple thing i'm using to learn a few framework. Each week someone in the office has to take a turn bringing in beers. This is done on a rotation, we take it in turns following a specific order. Occasionally someone isn't around and they skip their turn but will have to take it the following week  (or indeed the first subsequent week they can). Obviously we also have staff come and staff leave so this needs to be accounted for. Initially i'd modelled this in terms of drinkers and rounds. Each time someone bought a round they would be entered into the rounds table, whoever is first in the order with the least rounds is up next. This works perfectly until someone new joins as without inserting dummy data to cover all their "missing" rounds it will be their turn every time until they have caught up on the number of rounds everyone else has done.

This is currently what I have:

```
CREATE TABLE `rounds` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `drinker_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 

CREATE TABLE `drinkers` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Any ideas how I can re-model this in a way that will allow for people coming, and going, and people skipping their turn?

Thanks.

Comment: What's `updated_at` for?

Comment: `following a specific order` is an absolute requirement? You couldn't have it pick someone at random from the subset of drinkers who are due to buy a round?

Comment: @Strawberry updated_at isn't essential - just added automatically using a laravel migration

Comment: @Tim yep, otherwise there's a chance of people having to do it twice in a row which makes it pretty pricey. As it is, noone ever has to do it twice a month which means you only have to pay once per pay-packet

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends on how you define the subset of drinkers who are due to buy a round. Guaranteeing that the same person doesn't pay until they're due to pay may be easier than guaranteeing the payors follow a specific order.

Comment: How about if someone is away for a long time? Should they buy more often when they are back or start with the normal order?

Comment: Here's the algorithm I had in mind: "If I've paid within the past X weeks, then I'm not due to pay" -- where X = the number of current drinkers minus the number of drinkers who are unavailable for this round due to illness, say.

Comment: not really no - if someone was to miss a month or so then we would probably just skip them completely for a round

Comment: @Tim does that not assume though that someone being ill or off when its their turn then might not have to take part in that round at all when there's a good chance they were there for everyone else's rounds?

Comment: A person could conveniently "get sick" (lie about being sick) whenever it is their turn to pay, regardless of whether their turn was decided at random or by specified order. An algorithm that pops the payor from a queue is no less vulnerable to this phenomenon than an algorithm that grabs the payor at random out of a bag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need one table like

```
CREATE TABLE `drinkers` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `is_available` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `last_buy` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX(`last_buy`)
)
```

and you can get the person who needs to buy drinks like this

```
SELECT * FROM drinkers
WHERE is_available
ORDER BY last_buy ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would keep the drinkers (but add a flag if someone is sick - 0/1) and put rounds as this

```
CREATE TABLE `rounds` (
  `drinker_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `passed` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `passed_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  UNIQUE KEY (`id`)
)
```

Then put in round a record for every user with his ID and 0 for passed, 0000-00-00 00:00:00 for passed at. When someone buys drinks mark that in the 'rounds' table, with making passed to passed + 1 and updating the date. If some of the drinkers leaves work, remove him from rounds. If a new one comes add him to rounds with passed equals to the max passed values (give them a fresh start :) ). If some one is sick, he obviously can not buy drinks so someone else should. To define who should buy drinks, run this

```
SELECT r.passed, r.drinker_id
FROM drinkers d
JOIN rounds r ON d.id = r.drinker_id
WHERE d.sick = 0
ORDER BY r.passed DESC, d.id ASC
```

This will give you the driker with least times buying a drink.

In rounds table you will have somethin like that

```
drinker id, passed, date_passed
====================================
1           0       0000-00-00
2           1       2013-03-01
3           0       0000-00-00
```

Comment: Thanks. But.... with only 1 entry in the rounds table per drinker this removes the ability to add a description and store a date per-round. Also, it would be easier to just skip a person without having to first mark them as sick/absent as you would need to remember to revert this afterwards too.

Comment: And based on what you will skip a person? And how you will handle new people - add fake records for them? What about the people who leave or stop drinking? :)

Comment: registering a round would allow someone to get skipped

Comment: You can register a round with suggested system also. If you want to keep a record of all rounds them my suggestion would not work, of course.

Comment: yes good point. Does seem that people should be able to have the equivalent to a payment holiday (for illness/holiday etc) which I guess should be catered for